# Difference B/W A NIO Server And a Single Threaded Server

Tags: java, network-programming, nonblocking

I have been going through Java's NIO and have not been able to understand how it is actually helping me. Consider a server that listens on some port, and whenever a connection is established, serves that connection, and comes back to `socket.accept()`, waiting for new connection.

Now, if I were to write this server using NIO, I would register my `ServerSocketChannel` with a `Selector`, and then poll the `Selector` in a `while` loop to see if any event that I am interested in has taken place. If it has, then I get the `Set` of `SelectedKeys` and process each one of them.

While the processing is going on, I am not doing a `selector.select()`. So, even if a new event has taken place that I am interested in, I won't serve it! Just like in my previous server. While I am serving a request, I am not listening for any new incoming connections.

Won't I have to still spawn a new thread every time `selector.select()` returns > 0, so that I can keep on polling the `Selector`? Then this becomes a thread per connection design, that we have been doing with using any NIO for a long time.

What am I missing? How is NIO helping me scale?

Single-Threaded Server:

```
while(true) {
    Socket sock = serverSocketObject.accept();
    //serve this connection
}
```

Comment: nio uses more efficient transfers, more efficient listeners (selectors) and is generally better tuned than the original io routines. That is all.

Comment: Can you explain on that a bit more? How is it better than my single threaded server?

Comment: [Java NIO vs. IO](https://dzone.com/articles/java-nio-vs-io). Without seeing your single threaded server, or your other server, it's impossible to answer that. The nio routines should be compared to the IO routines; why do you think your threading model is relevant to that?

Comment: I have updated my post with the single threaded server. I am comparing the two since it is said that NIO uses far lesser threads than a thread-per-connection model. My point of contention is that even if I am using a single thread to monitor all the channels in NIO and serve any ready channels, the responsiveness of my server is going down, as it would in a single threaded server.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for your response. I have not been able to understand how NIO is helping me work with lesser amounts of threads while not me having to compromise on my server's responsiveness.

Comment: Look up [Zero-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy)